# Automate Copy Set Column from Document to Document in Excel OS X

Tags: ios, excel, vba, macos

I am not very technical minded, but know enough to follow the most basic instructions.

I need to copy certain rows from one Excel to another. For example, I have been given a huge Excel and I need to take from 6 columns only, Column T, Column AP, Column FL

I want to create a macro to enable me to do this. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  Show what you have tried, and explain which bit isn't working properly, and we can help you fix it.  Other than that, all we can tell you is to use something like `someworkbook.sourceworksheet.Columns("T").Copy anotherworkbook.destinationworksheet.Columns("A")`.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K. I have tried searching the internet for the code I need, so I have tried various scripts but I think my lack of understanding is what is holding me back. The rule you have gave me, this is how wet behind the ears I am, how do I apply that to my page, ie, where do I enter the name of the worksheet I am copying from, and copying to? Lets say for example my worksheet with the copy is called 'Dave' and the new one is 'Fred'.

**Dave**workbook.sourceworksheet.Columns("T").Copy anotherworkbook.destination**Fred**worksheet.Columns("A")

Comment: If you show what you have tried so far we can possibly help you fix it.  Without your code as a base, we would have to write everything from scratch - and SO is not a "code for me" site.  It's a "please help me fix this bit I am stuck on, as nowhere else on the internet (and definitely not anywhere on SO) is the answer shown" site.

Comment: Fair enough, point taken. I needed a starting point as I am new to it all. I will continue my search and try and figure it out. Thanks for taking the time to reply regardless YowE3K